# jQuery Very Slow during Loop, what can I improve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, loops

I have some code that is loading about 5,000 rows of data from a database. Once the AJAX call fetches the rows, it passes them to my function to create the rows. This function loops over the JSON data, creates our TR's, does some lookup's and then finally appends the full concatenated output to the DOM.

On document load, I fetch 1,000 records and append it to the DOM for the user so they can see some of the data. I then have an AJAX call behind the scenes get the rest of it and append it when its done. The browser is locking up during this time though when it is looping over the data.

During my testing, I commented out the `each loop` and the issue went away so I have narrowed it down to that. I am just not sure how I can improve this or if its the lookup function for `getObjects` that is delaying it.

In the code sample below, the slowness begins at `$(data['data']['results']['data']).each(function() {`, at least, that's the block of code I commented out and it ran smoothly.

Without leaving the question too open for resolution, what other options can i take aside from the `$.each` loop that may improve this or is it something happening within the loop that could be causing the slowness?

```
// Given data, create our table rows
function createRows(data) {

    // Define our vars
    var output = '',
        markup = '';

    // Add the fields we chose to export to the array
    // We will then check this array when printing the columns to see if it should be shown or not
    if (isset(data.data.exportFields)) {
        $(data.data.exportFields.export).each(function() {
            exportFields.push(this.fieldID);
        });
    }

    // Loop over the core data
    $(data['data']['results']['data']).each(function() {

        // First level of data in our XML output
        core = $(this)[0];

        // Loop over our fields
        $(core['fields']['data']).each(function() {

            // Set a var for the field level data
            field = $(this)[0];

            // Do we have markup?
            if (isset(data.data.markup)) {
                markup = '';
                if (typeof getObjects(data.data.markup.data, 'QID', core.QID)[0] !== 'undefined') {
                    markup = getObjects(data.data.markup.data, 'QID', core.QID)[0].markup;
                }
            }

            output += '<tr class="primaryValue ' + markup + '" data-qid="' + core.QID + '">';

            // Loop over all the other rows 2 through x
            $.each(field, function(key, value) {

                // Field Name Lookup
                key = key.replace(/_/gi, '');
                FieldNameLookup = getObjects(cfgFields.data.fields.options, 'FieldID', key)[0];
                x = FieldNameLookup.FieldName;
                val = (value.length ? value : '-')

                // Is this an email address?
                if (x.match(/email/gi)) {
                    output += '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="small ' + (jQuery.inArray(key, exportFields) != -1 ? 'hidden' : '') + '">';
                    output += '<a href="mailto:' + val + '" class="">' + val + '</a>';
                    output += '</td>';
                } else if (x.match(/NTID/gi)) {
                    output += '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="small ' + (jQuery.inArray(key, exportFields) != -1 ? 'hidden' : '') + '">';
                    output += '<a href="https://website.com/profile/' + val + '" target="_BLANK" class="">' + val + '</a>';
                    output += '</td>';
                } else {
                    output += '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="small ' + (jQuery.inArray(key, exportFields) != -1 ? 'hidden' : '') + ' allowContext">';
                    output += val;
                    output += '</td>';
                }

            });

            // End our row
            output += '<td data-tableexport-display="always" class="notesTD allowContext hidden"></td>';
            output += '</tr>'

        });
    });

    // Append the results to the DOM
    $('[name=resultsTable]').append(output);

}

function getObjects(obj, key, val) {
    var objects = [];
    for (var i in obj) {
        if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
        if (typeof obj[i] == 'object') {
            objects = objects.concat(getObjects(obj[i], key, val));
        } else if (i == key && obj[key] == val) {
            objects.push(obj);
        }
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to implement some form of paging? Loading that much data at once can cause the client to run very slowly.  You are already just showing 1000 records, simply get the next 1000 when the user gets to that point in the page.

Comment: I'd suggest doing the parsing and markup-generation on the server-side, if that's working at a reasonable speed. Use AJAX to fetch formatted HTML, rather than JSON. (One tiny thing you can do, though is lose `= $(this)[0]`, which is no different to `= this`.)

Comment: Well I am kinda doing that. If there are 10,000 results total, it will load 1,000 up front and then iterate and do ajax calls behind the scenes in groups of 1,000. The issue though is during those behind the scenes calls, the browser locks up because of this loop

Comment: Even retrieving 1000 records is a lot. 100 is more than enough for a user to process at once. You then don't need any loops to get more data. You either retrieve it when the user clicks a button to get the next page, or use infinite scrolling to get the page when the user nears the bottom of the page

Comment: @lonesomeday I removed the [0] and got an error that something was undefined.

Comment: So one option would be to stop executing that loop and only grab chunks when the user gets to that point.  Doing what lonesomeday suggest is also a good enhancement

Comment: `$(this)[0]` is exactly the same as `this`

Comment: easy, less nested looping. Basically, look at your looping strategy and find a way to flatten it out a bit.

Comment: All those calls to that `getObjects()` function are probably a large fraction of the cost.

Comment: Currently you're looping over each row, then each field, then for each field, over all of the fields again minus the first and those after and including the current field, that's going to add up to quite a bit. Do you really need that inner-most loop? How can we remove it?

Comment: @KevinB - I will look into trying to get rid of that and possibly run a function at the end that turns the email addresses into links etc.

Comment: @KevinB Looking at the structure, I am not sure how I would get rid of that. Its parent is creating the table row and the inner loop is creating the columns. By removing the inner loop, it would be a row with one column.

Answer (score 1):

There several things here. You have three layer nested loop.The more nested loops you have the slower the loop can get. It would probably be most efficient to breakout the loops into their own functions because they have their own purpose. It would be easier to modify and reason about them that way. The main reason is that even-though you maybe bringing back 1,000 records the internal loops also have to complete based on the length of the arrays that they are fed.

Another slow point in my opinion is the way that you are creating your DOM elements. Instead of creating them in strings and concatenating those together you can create them with jQuery of Pure JavaScript and cache them in a variable. You them populate their attributes and content in the loop.

[Javascript BEST PRACTICES PART 2](https://www.thinkful.com/learn/javascript-best-practices-2/)

[Learn the slow (and fast) way to append elements to the DOM](https://howchoo.com/g/mmu0nguznjg/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom)

[enter link description here](http://gregfranko.com/blog/jquery-best-practices/)

Comment: Thanks for the links, I will try and implement some of those best practices to see what I can come up with

Comment: I re-wrote everything in functions within PHP and make an AJAX call to that page to fetch the table data. That is nice and fast now but as soon as I try to append that data to the DOM, locks up like before :/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend breaking the loop into smaller functions (maybe even recursive functions), and pass a html as a node, not as text (so browser doesn't have to re-render).

Like so, but you would have to fill-in some blanks:

```
function makeTd() {
  var hidden = exportFields.indexOf(key) > -1 ? "hidden" : "";
  var td = document.createElement('td');
  td.setAttribute('data-tableexport-display', 'always');
  td.className = "small";
  // conditionals for email, etc.
  return td;
}

function makeTr() {
  var tr = document.creatElement('tr');
  tr.className = "primaryValue";
  // logic ...
  return tr
}

$data.map(function(core, ci){

  core.map(function(field, fi) {
    var tr = makeTr();

    Object.key(field).map(function(output) {
      var key = output;
      var value = field[output];
      var td = makeTd(key, value);
      tr.appendChild(td);
    });

    var endTd = document.createElement('td');
    tr.appendChild(endTd);
  });
});
```